# Detectar cambio en JSON

Tags: php, python, json, api, web

os pongo en situación, tengo una API que me devuelve el JSON (por ejemplo http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22) a la que solo puedo acceder para obtener los datos, no puedo tocar su código.

Me gustaría saber cada vez que hay un cambio en el JSON (por ejemplo temp, pressure, temp_max) para hacer algo en programación, por ejemplo escribir en un txt.

Normalmente uso PHP, pero no encuentro nada con lo que hacer esto, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida sea cual sea el lenguaje, siempre que sea orientado a web, para mostrar los resultados.

Comment: has pensado en ir descargando el json cada x segundos, almacenarlos en un string y hacer algo similar al equals de c#?

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, en php hay algo similar y en python como bien ha comentado @abulafia

Answer (score 1):

Para python existe una biblioteca llamada [`jsondiff`](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff) que puede ser útil, junto con la biblioteca [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

En el siguiente ejemplo nos bajamos cada 10 minutos el JSON, y aplico `diff` entre lo que nos acabamos de bajar y lo que habíamos bajado en la iteración anterior [Nota: en el *free plan*, la api de OpenWeather actualiza sus datos [cada 2h](https://openweathermap.org/price), así que puedes aumentar sin problemas el tiempo de muestreo, ya que este ejemplo no produciría resultados hasta haber ejecutado unas 12 veces el bucle).

```py
import time    
import requests
from jsondiff import diff


api_url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22'
data = requests.get(api_url).json()

while (True):
  time.sleep(10*60)
  newdata = requests.get(api_url).json()
  diferencia = diff(newdata, data)
  if diferencia:
    print(diferencia)
  data = newdata
```

En este ejemplo me limito a guardar el resultado del diff (que será un diccionario vacío en caso de que no haya habido cambios), e imprimirlo seguidamente si hubo cambios. Pero puedes hacer cualquier otra cosa a partir de ese resultado. Mírate la documentación de `jsondiff` para ver qué estructura tiene el json que te retorna `diff` cuando sí hubo cambios.

Comment: gracias! esto me viene perfecto para lo que tengo en mente.

Comment: @alebupal Por cierto... para probar si funcionaba bien, lo puse en marcha ayer. Hace una petición cada 10 minutos. Tras más de 24 horas funcionando, aún no ha detectado ningún diff... Parece que esa API no actualiza datos muy a menudo.

Comment: no te preocupes, lo que tengo pensando no tiene nada que ver con el tiempo, esa API es la primera que pille por internet como ejemplo.